# How to convert json array from string to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to convert a string object to an object in javascript. I want to iterate through the data inside of it to display on my UI. Is there any way i can convert this string array of objects into an object. I already used JSON.parse but nothing seems happening.

[image]

Using JSON.parse:

```
$.each(agent_coaching_data, function(index, row_data) {
    JSON.parse(row_data["coaching_data"]);
});
```

Using JSON.stringify:

```
$.each(agent_coaching_data, function(index, row_data) {
    JSON.parse(row_data["coaching_data"]);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.parse(row_data["coaching_data"]))`.

Comment: i tried it, it worked, but only when you console log it

Comment: Note `JSON.parse()` does not change the value of the property in place, you need to do an assignment ie `row_data["coaching_data"]=JSON.parse(...)` to change it

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt, the result of the json parsing was not assigned anywhere... Try this way:

```
$.each(agent_coaching_data, function(index, row_data) {
  agent_coaching_data[index]["coaching_data"] = JSON.parse(row_data["coaching_data"]);
});
```